# Golang использования sync.Mutex

Tags: golang, указатели, rest, mutex

Нужно ли использовать sync.Mutex в данном usecase?

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

type Rest struct {
    client       *http.Client
    clientMutext sync.Mutex
}

func (rr *Rest) installHttpHandler() {
    handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        rr.clientMutext.Lock()
        defer rr.clientMutext.Unlock()
        rr.client.Do() //работа с http.Client
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func main() {
    r := Rest{
        client: &http.Client{},
    }
    r.installHttpHandler()
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Смущает то что rr.client (*http.Client) является глобальным для Rest.
Или можно безопасно получать доступ к rr.client не используя sync.Mutex?

представленный код написан чтобы продемонстрировать проблему ответ на который я хочу получить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читайте внимательно
[документацию](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client):

> (…)
>
> *The Client's Transport typically has internal state (cached TCP
> connections), so Clients should be reused instead of created as needed.
> **Clients are safe for concurrent use by multiple
> goroutines.***
>
> (…)

Comment: Спасибо.   
А если в структуре будет объект типа:


`type Rest struct {   
    data *customStruct     
}`


тогда для обращения к полю data придется использовать mutex?

Comment: Да.  `net/http.Client` потокобезопасен, потому что внутри имеет мутексы.  Для собственных структур эту потокобезопасность надо обеспечивать самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо, а как вы считаете использовать подобную конструкцию Rest.httpClient имеет смысл? или стоит создавать отдельный экземпляр http.Client внутри каждого запроса?

Comment: Ответ на этот вопрос _буквально_ в том же параграфе документации :-P